# ChaplinJS: Referencing a CollectionView property in its template

Tags: chaplinjs

I have a Collection in ChaplinJS that has the following initialization code:

```
Chaplin = require 'chaplin'
Collection = require 'models/base/collection'
Domain = require 'models/domain'
mediator = require 'mediator'

module.exports = class Domains extends Collection

  model: Domain

  # Initialize the SyncMachine
  _(@prototype).extend Chaplin.SyncMachine

  initialize: ->
    super
    @.totalHits = 0
```

How can I reference `totalHits` in the template of its view? I am using handlebars templates, and writing `{{totalHits}}` returns nothing.

Incidentally, shouldn't I be able to rewrite the above code with:

```
module.exports = class Domains extends Collection

  model: Domain
  totalHits: 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

In my `CollectionView` I can override `getTemplateData` and pass into it whatever I want, including the complete collection object:

```
  getTemplateData: ->
    templateData = super
    templateData.collection = @.collection
    templateData
```

Then in the handlebars template I can do `{{collection.totalHits}}`